Is the approximation valid when considering derivative of integral of a non-analytical function?
Consider a two-variable real function $f(x,y)$ who has only one singularity point (0,0)
in the domain of definition with
$\lim_{x->0}lim_{y->0}f(x,y)=0,\lim_{y->0}lim_{x->0}f(x,y)=1$
Now we are intersted in the term
$I = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \int_a^b{f(x,y) g(x)dx}$
where $a < 0 < b$ and $g(x)$ is an analytical function.
If we want to calculate the discontinuity
$lim_{y->0+}{I} - lim_{y->0-}{I}$
can $g(x)$ replaced by $g(0)$ in the integral?
How to prove it?
I guess this statement because I think the discontinuity of the derivative only depends on the neighborhood of (0,0).
